# How to Work With GUI button in unity

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I want to get user input through GUI Button in unity3d unityscript. I have write this script to get user input through keyboard

```
var f_hor : float = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
//Get Vertical move - move forward or backward
var f_ver : float = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
if (f_ver < 0) {
b_isBackward = true;
} else {
b_isBackward = false;
}
```

its work fine and its give me 0 and 1 accordingly..But i want the same action through GUI button.Like if i have four GUI button..and they work same as this did...I can make GUI button in ONGUI function..But how can i achieve this functionaility...Any help

Answer (score 0):

Altough I don't know if it is the best way to go (Unity's gui element are not the best for ingame HUD or menu), this should do the job:

```
private bool buttonPressed = false;

public void Update()
{
    if (buttonPressed)
    {
         //do what you want

         buttonPressed = false;
    }
}
```

Sorry for using `C#` code, but I don't know `JS`. It should be easy to translate tough.

```
public void OnGui()
{
    Rect rect = new Rect(...); //your button dimension

    if (GUI.Button(rect, "AButton")
    {
        buttonPressed = true;
    }
}
```

---

EDIT:

If you want to manually handle input from mouse you can use methods of [MonoBehavior](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html) such as [OnMouseDown](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html) or [OnMouseUp](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseUp.html).

Alternatively you can check from inside `Update` if a mouse event occured, have a look at [Input.GetMouseButton](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButton.html) or similar methods of `Input` class.

Comment: I have done all of my work in Update function..and instead of Update if i do all the work in ONGUI function this work fine..but now i have one problem...how can i get contineous input when i press the GUI button just like when i press arrow key i get the contineous input till that i have press the keybord button...

Comment: @user1594794: basically you can't. OnGUI isn't call continuosly like Update. That's why I split it in 2 functions in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply @Hesenbug....I have one prolem on gui Button..When i press GUI button and hold it my player will continue to move and animation will run just like when i press uparrow key...how can i do ths..

Comment: I suggest you not to use button for this. Use 2d texture to display buttons and handle mouse input manually.

Comment: I am making game for android ...So is it good to move character through finger touch..or is it possible and if then any link to this..thanks in advance